# Why does the value of int changes even if I don't change it?

Tags: c

I'm trying to save the values to an int array from a string but when I run it the fifth element changes in value even if I don't change it.

Here is my program. It accepts one argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *mainDest = argv[1];
    char *busy;
    int a = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int *addr;
    //int addr[5];
    int i = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    addr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    busy = (char *) malloc(2);
    while(mainDest[a] != '\0')
        {
            if(mainDest[a] != ':')
            {
                printf("%c\n", mainDest[a]);
                busy[b] = mainDest[a];
                b++;
            }
            if(mainDest[a] == ':')
            {
                if(isdigit(busy[0]) == 1){
                    printf("converting to integer %s\n", busy);
                    printf("i is %d\n", i);
                    addr[i] = atoi(busy);
                    printf("address is %d\n", addr[i]);
                    printf("5th address is %d\n", addr[4]);
                    i++;
                    b = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("5th address is %d\n", addr[4]);
                    addr[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                    b = 0;
                }
                if(mainDest[a] == ':' && mainDest[a+1] == ':' )
                {
                    printf("a is %d\n", a);
                    printf("i is %d\n", i);
                    addr[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                    a++;
                }
            }
            a++;
        }
        if(isdigit(busy[0]) == 1)
        {
            printf("converting to integer %s\n", busy);
            printf("i is %d\n", i);
            addr[i] = atoi(busy);
            i++;
            b = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            addr[i] = 0;
            i++;
            b = 0;
        }
        printf("address is %d\n", addr[i]);
        printf("5th address is %d\n", addr[4]);
        printf("how many i's: %d\n", i);
        printf("After while loop.\n");
    while(c != i+1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", addr[c]);
        c++;
    } 
    free(addr);
}
```

I run this from the terminal - ./a.out 8:7:6:5:4:3:2:1

```
8
converting to integer 8
i is 0
address is 8
5th address is 56
7
converting to integer 7
i is 1
address is 7
5th address is 55
6
converting to integer 6
i is 2
address is 6
5th address is 54
5
converting to integer 5
i is 3
address is 5
5th address is 53
4
converting to integer 4
i is 4
address is 4
5th address is 4
3
converting to integer 3
i is 5
address is 3
5th address is 51
2
converting to integer 2
i is 6
address is 2
5th address is 50
1
converting to integer 1
i is 7
address is 0
5th address is 49
how many i's: 8
After while loop.
8
7
6
5
49
3
2
1
0
```

As you can see I always print out the value of fifth element even if I haven't store anything to see why it changes. The result is it changes every time I call it. Any suggestions helps, thanks.

Comment: `addr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));` should be `addr = malloc(5 * sizeof *addr);`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have not checked if there is a program argument. It should be routine to do this.

```
if (argc < 2)
    { /*error*/ }
```

You did not allocate enough memory for the `int[]` array. I would suggest either a `#define` to state the number of elements or a `const int`.

```
#define ELEMS 5
```

Add to that, you've casted the return value from `malloc()` (unnecessary) but not checked the return value (necessary).

```
addr = malloc(ELEMS * sizeof(int));
if (addr == NULL)
    { /*error*/ }
```

In both cases adding the code is simple compared to the grief it can otherwise cause.

Comment: ... or as @chux advises, use the size of the type you assign to.